# Вставка данных, оператор MERGE для Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть у меня данные они не в таблице, ну вот получаю данные из переменных, и есть таблица в базе данных, как можно сделать вставку данных в таблицу, которая в базе, при помощи оператора MERGE. Дело в том, что я смотрел примеры в интернетах, но там всегда есть одна таблица, и есть другая таблица, вот они так и сливаются при помощи этого оператора типа upset. А как можно брать данные не из другой таблицы (например данные получаются в результате вычислений) и поместить их в этот оператор.
Сейчас данные добавляются так

```
INSERT INTO ADDFIELDS (ADDFIELDID, DESCRIPTION, FIELDTYPE) VALUES('0', 'проба', 'Строка')";
```

Но  это не эффективно, хочу использовать merge.Но по логике понимаю как он работает, а по синтаксису не получается написать.
Переменные VALUES('0', 'проба', 'Строка')"; получаются в результате выполнения метода на c# далее у меня есть подключение к базе, и вот в нем мне нужно вставить запрос на вставку данных. Причем если запись есть уже в базе, то  она обновляется полностью (все поля).

Сама таблица, куда я хочу вставить данные выглядит так.

```
ALTER TABLE KANCHDATA.ADDFIELDS
 DROP PRIMARY KEY CASCADE;

DROP TABLE KANCHDATA.ADDFIELDS CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE KANCHDATA.ADDFIELDS
(
  ADDFIELDID             NUMBER(5)              NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION            VARCHAR2(250 CHAR),
  FIELDTYPE              VARCHAR2(250 CHAR),
  "OptimisticLockField"  INTEGER,
  "GCRecord"             INTEGER
)
TABLESPACE QDISR_DATA
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
MONITORING;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX KANCHDATA.ADDFIELDS_PK ON KANCHDATA.ADDFIELDS
(ADDFIELDID)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE QDISR_DATA
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           );

CREATE INDEX KANCHDATA."iGCRecord_ADDFIELDS" ON KANCHDATA.ADDFIELDS
("GCRecord")
LOGGING
TABLESPACE QDISR_DATA
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           );

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER KANCHDATA.ADDFIELDIDFILL_TRG 
BEFORE INSERT
ON KANCHDATA.ADDFIELDS
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
tmpVar NUMBER;
BEGIN
   tmpVar := 0;

   SELECT ADDFIELD_id_seq.NEXTVAL INTO tmpVar FROM dual;
   :NEW.ADDFIELDID := tmpVar;

   EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
       RAISE;
END ADDFIELDIDFILL_TRG;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER KANCHDATA.ADDFIELDS_CH_TRG 
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON KANCHDATA.ADDFIELDS REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
DECLARE
BEGIN
insert into tablechangehistory values ('ADDFIELDS',sysdate,'');
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
   RAISE;
END ADDFIELDS_CH_TRG;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM KANCHPROD.SYNP_ADDFIELDS FOR KANCHDATA.ADDFIELDS;


ALTER TABLE KANCHDATA.ADDFIELDS ADD (
  CONSTRAINT ADDFIELDS_PK
  PRIMARY KEY
  (ADDFIELDID)
  USING INDEX KANCHDATA.ADDFIELDS_PK
  ENABLE VALIDATE);

GRANT SELECT ON KANCHDATA.ADDFIELDS TO KANCHPROD;
```

Comment: используйте `With` или напишите просто нужный вам запрос и делайте `merge`   с ним

Comment: @Viktorov  а можно пример простой увидеть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш запрос `INSERT INTO ADDFIELDS (ADDFIELDID, DESCRIPTION, FIELDTYPE) VALUES('0', 'проба', 'Строка')`, с учетом, что наличие записи ищется по полю ADDFIELDID, преобразуется в MERGE следующим образом:

```
merge into ADDFIELDS S
using (select 0 as fieldID, 'проба' as descr, 'Строка' as type from DUAL) N
   on (N.fieldID=S.ADDFIELDID)
when not matched then
  insert(ADDFIELDID, DESCRIPTION, FIELDTYPE) values(N.fieldID, N.descr, N.type)
when matched then
  update set S.DESCRIPTION=N.descr, S.FIELDTYPE=N.type
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, ну вот я и не мог сообразить как это делается в простых случаях, только ваш запрос в TOAD не проходит, лягушка ругается на название  ADDFIELDS

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Слово into перед ним потерял. сейчас написал

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, только теперь ошибка в операторе as. так лягушка говорит.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Значит его надо убрать :)

Comment: )) теперь ругается на on N.fieldID=S.ADDFIELDID именно N

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Блин, надо было все таки оракловый за основу для ответа брать. взял от ms sql, вот и результат ... В общем оракл еще требует что бы условия ON были в скобках

Comment: Круто , вот теперь заработало, спасибо,буду изучать

Answer (score 1):

Например вот так вот:

```
MERGE INTO animalia d
USING (WITH X AS 
       (SELECT  'moo' AS COW, 'woof' AS CAT, 
                (SELECT MAX( DECIBELS ) 
                   FROM ANIMALIA 
                  WHERE COW = 'moo' ) AS DECIBELS
          FROM DUAL )
       SELECT * FROM X) q ON (1 = 1)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET d.cow = q.cow||' and more';
```

Стащил пример с [en-so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673806/oracle-with-clause-merge-syntax-error).

[Документация](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2077142)

Comment: Это я видел, и таких примеров много. Но у меня сейчас стоит запрос INSERT OR REPLACE 
INTO ADDFIELDS (ADDFIELDID, DESCRIPTION, FIELDTYPE) 
VALUES(0, dfgresg, строка) , у меня есть такие переменные VALUES(0, dfgresg, строка), как мне сделать запрос по сути такой же только с Merge

Comment: А проблема то в чем? Что именно у вас не получается? Добавьте ваши попытки в вопрос, опишите, что именно не получается. Я показал, как использовать данные в результате вычислений и теперь не понимаю, что еще тут может быть не понятно

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Приведите этот запрос в тексте вопроса. А так же укажите критерии замены строки, т.е. какие из полей составляют уникальный ключ, а какие надо обновлять при существовании записи. Без этого никто не сможет понять, как именно должен выглядеть merge в вашем случае

Comment: Поправил вопрос.